# Google Cloud Console Virtual Machine Mysteriously Deleted

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

This morning I logged into my pc and attempted to access remotely into a VM I have. `No connection` was the reported error. I log into my cloud console to find no projects.

Google Support is not available for me, as I have bronze package and I do not have 150$ available to upgrade it.

Are there any logs that could explain what happened? Did it just get wiped out? The instance is still there. But the machine itself is gone. I can't find any records of it. Please advise any help you can.

Comment: Are you on the free tier account? If so, you will need to enable billing. What do you mean by "the instance is still there but the machine itself is gone"? Google provides free support for billing questions. Ask them if your account was shutdown due to billing issues.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question also confuses others, what do you mean by "The instance is still there. But the machine itself is gone"? 
Because you also mentioned "I log into my cloud console to find no projects. ", which means you should see nothing before you choose a valid project

Please be more specific about your questions

Answer (score 0):

Could you indicate us step by step what you do in the Google Cloud Platform console? Where you click and what you type.

Please, check also the Activity tab on the home page of the console. Once in it, on the right-hand side, select Resource type: GCE VM instance, to see modifications in VMs.

We need to know exactly what you are seeing on each step, and any error code. Then we could see if the problem is in your procedure, or if there is an issue you should report to [billing support](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing), which is free, as pointed out by John Hanley in his comment.

Please, when you do this, make sure you don't include any personal information in the data you post here (such as project ID or password).